# How to resolve Resource entry already defined

Tags: android, string, cmake, android-source

I am using aosp and after running the command:

```
make 2>&1 | tee build-log.txt
```

I am getting lots of errors, such as:

```
packages/apps/Settings/res/values/aliases.xml:19: error: Resource entry confirm_lock_pattern is already defined.
res/layout/confirm_lock_pattern.xml:0: Originally defined here.

packages/apps/Settings/res/values/aliases.xml:20: error: Resource entry confirm_lock_password is already defined.
res/layout/confirm_lock_password.xml:0: Originally defined here.

packages/apps/Settings/res/values/strings.xml:5193: error: Resource entry enable_verbose_log_vpu is already defined.
packages/apps/Settings/res/values/strings.xml:5189: Originally defined here.
```

When I checked in particular files aliases.xml and strings.xml,

aliases.xml:

```
<item name="confirm_lock_pattern" type="layout">@layout/confirm_lock_pattern_base</item>
 <item name="confirm_lock_password" type="layout">@layout/confirm_lock_password_base</item>
```

strings.xml:

Comment: Why is this question tagged `cmake`? Did you use CMake to configure the project?

Comment: Kinda straightforward isn't it? You have layout confirm_lock_pattern defined in it's own xml, and as an alias in aliases.xml . Remove one

Comment: I removed that but even after removing, I get error as no resource values found to match confirm_lock_password. I used clean, clear cache and restart but this error is not resolving.

Comment: I checked my Android 7.1 local tree. I don't have a res/layout/confirm_lock_pattern.xml just res/layout/confirm_lock_pattern_base.xml and the declaration in aliases.
Try removing the res/layout/confirm_lock_pattern.xml and leave the aliases.xml one ( maybe you did the opposite? )